# Compiling and linking in nasm

Tags: gcc, nasm, elf, i386

I'm trying to link some assembly files, but I'm having some problems. I use `nasm` and I make my object file with:

```
nasm -f elf -o task1.o task1.asm
```

and when I try to link it with some other files with:

```
gcc -o task1 task1.o asm_io.o
```

I get error:

```
i386 architecture of input file 'task1.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

and same error for file asm_io.o.

My Ubutnu is 64-bit.
When I try command:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o task1.o task1.asm
```

I get error that instructions `pusha` and `popa` are not supported in 64-bit mode.
Can you tell me what instructions to use instead of `pusha` and `popa`, and what gcc command to use?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me what instructions to use instead of `pusha` and `popa`, and what gcc command to use?

Please see [stackoverflow/6837392](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837392/how-to-save-the-registers-on-x86-64-for-an-interrupt-service-routine) for suggestions on how to code equivalents for `PUSHA` and `POPA`.

If you wish to build a 32 bit binary on your 64 bit host, you will need to explicitly specify the `-m32` switch to GCC, and will need to have a 32 bit development environment installed.
Please see the [discussion about multi-arch support](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998047) and the [Installing Compilers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) community wiki page for more information about building 32 bit programs on Ubuntu.